# I have problems when I try un scale and unscale X and y arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I receive "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2." when I try to scale and reverse the X and y variables for a machine learning use case.

I have a time series dataset and I am trying to scale  the input X and output y, train variables and reverse the predictions. I am using LSTM NN.

1. The shape of variables for the train dataset:

   - X_train.shape = (812, 7, 2)
   - y_train.shape = (812, 2)

812 = number of samples, 7 = no. of steps in LSTM, 2 = no of steps out (predictions) of LSTM NN

2. The variables for the test dataset:

   - X_test.shape = (93, 7, 2)
   - y_test.shape = (93, 2)

I defined two MinMaxScaler objects, one for X and one for y:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1)).fit(X_train)
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1)).fit(y_train)
```

Error is: "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2."

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-d0dcd048aa92> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
----> 2 X_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1)).fit(X_train)
      3 # X_scaler = StandardScaler()
      4 
      5 y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1)).fit(y_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    323         # Reset internal state before fitting
    324         self._reset()
--> 325         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    326 
    327     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    351         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy,
    352                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 353                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    354 
    355         data_min = np.nanmin(X, axis=0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    537         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    538             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 539                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

As said, your Scaler needs a 2d input. You can do this like in the following:

```
mms = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = mms.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(817,-1)).reshape(817,7,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn MinMaxScaler is expecting 2d num arrays as input but you are passing in is a 3d array you need to reshape the array into a 2d.

So, shaped data into 2D then normalized/standardize it. Further reshape it to 3D and use it in LSTM

Comment: X_train[0:2]  What is the correct reshaping cmd? 
array([[[ -0.0625    ,   0.        ],
        [ -0.33333333,   0.        ],
        [ -1.14583333,   0.        ],
        [  1.64583333,   0.        ],
        [ -3.52083333,   0.        ],
        [ -9.60416667,   0.        ],
        [-11.39583333,   0.        ]],

       [[ -0.33333333,   0.        ],
        [ -1.14583333,   0.        ],
        [  1.64583333,   0.        ],
        [ -3.52083333,   0.        ],
        [ -9.60416667,   0.        ],
        [-11.39583333,   0.        ],
        [-11.52083333,   0.        ]]])

Comment: Why dont you standardise/normalize your data, then reshape it to 3d to work with LSTM

Comment: Ok. I've got it. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I did: shaped data into 2D and normalized it. Then I reshaped it to 3D and used it in LSTM